# want to select Cell that has specific condition

Tags: excel, vba

Want to select the rows, which has values greater than or equal to "2.5" in column "H"
then want to select adjacent rows to that row. so that I can copy them to a new sheet
For example (Plz refer Attached Image) 
     I want to select rows 409 410 411 because row 410 has a value equal to "2.5" in 
     column "H"
Please suggest a VBA Code, My trial code looks like this 

    `Sub Selectrows()
      Dim lastrow As Long
      Dim i As Range
     lastrow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
      For Each i In Range("H4:H" & lastrow)
         If i.Value >= 2.5 Then
          i.Select
          ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
     End If
     Next I
    End Sub`

[image]

PS : Sorry for my English, I'm new to English and VBA

[Problem with the answered code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N74M.png)

Comment: @braX okay, I tried but didn't reach to a constructive code...I'm still trying

Comment: look into [`Find()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)` method and [`Offset()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset)` and [`Resize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)` properties of `Range` object

Comment: @HTH Thanks, I'll see them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible enhancement of your code (explanation in comments)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Selectrows()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim cel As Range

    Dim destSht As Worksheet
    Set destSht = Worksheets("myDestinationSheetName") '<-- change "myDestinationSheetName" to your actual destination sheet name

    With Worksheets("mySourceSheetName") ' reference source sheet -  change "mySourceSheetName" to your actual source sheet name
        lastrow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' get referenced sheet column E last not empty cell row index
        For Each cel In .Range("H4:H" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas) ' loop through referenced sheet column H cells cointaining formulas from row 4 down to column E las not empty one
            If cel.Value >= 2.5 Then cel.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(3, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

as you see I suggest

- to use `With .. End With block` to reference a specific object (`Worksheets("mySourceSheetName")` in this case) and inside it use dots (.) before each of its child member (like Range, Cells, …) to be make sure they do belong to referenced object
- to use `SpecialCells()` method of `Range` object to filter only cells with "constant" (i.e. not deriving from formulas) content
- to use `.Offset()` property to offset the the range object it's being called on (`cel` in this case) one row up and zero column aside
- to use `.Resize()` property to widen the range object it's being called on (`cel.Offset(-1,0)` in this case) to three rows in height and one column in width

Comment: @surendrachoudhary, any feedback?

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. now It's showing "no cells were found" error while executing 'for each' loop line

Comment: That means no "constant" cells have been found from H4 down to column H last not empty one: are they "formulas" cells?. If you found my code useful, you can upvote it

Comment: yes, they are formula cells, can you please tell another method for formula cells without copying and pasting as constants.

Comment: I'll surely upvote it, I got my answer as well as I learned too much from your answer.

Comment: Fine. And if my answer solves your question then you may want to mark it as accepted as well and direct future readers, too...

Comment: use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)` instead of `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`: see edited answer

Comment: It's selecting cells with values <= 2.5 also while executing your code. I've attached a screenshot in the question section. plz help with it

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the `If cel.Value >= 2.5 Then...`, run the code line and once it stops there use Immediate Window (ctrl-G to pop it out) to query `?cell.Value` and see the outcome. BTW, the code in your image shows that you are _always_ copying since `Selection.Copy` is outside the `If Then` statement. BTW2: should_"I got my answer as well as I learned too much from your answer"_ still be true, you may take your time to upvote and mark the answer as accepted to direct future readers, too...

Comment: added xlnumbers to  SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlnumbers), now its selecting cells with values >= 2.5 but now the problem is that while copying the results to destination sheets, it overrides the rows and eventually ended up copying the last rows only.     plz suggest solution

Comment: the `....Offset(1)` at the end of the `Destination` parameter of `Copy` statement prevents such an overwting: are you sure you're executing my very code?

Comment: for seeing the changes, I changed the offset(1) to offset(4),  It inserts 4 rows before the pasting the results. so its overwrites and displays last result only